# Center grid of inline-blocks within container

Tags: css

I have a set of inline-block div's within container. I want this divs to form a proper "table-like" grid, with elements aligned to the left, so if the last row of grid  will contain less elements than others, the grid wil not be broken.

Also, the grid itself needs to be centered relative to container.

Here is illustration to what I need: http://note.io/157hjk1

The obvious way is to put grid inside wrapper, set `text-align: left` for wrapper and center wrapper itself within parent container.

But the width of a wrapper in that case will not fit the sum of length of elements in a single row, but to a width of container instead.

The usual solution - set `display:inline-block` for wrapper does not work in that case, probably because of inline-blocks within wrapper.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="square">1</div>
        <div class="square">2</div>
        <div class="square">3</div>
        <div class="square">4</div>
        <div class="square">5</div>
        <div class="square">6</div>
        <div class="square">7</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.square {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.wrap{
     border: 1px solid green;
}

.container{
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

JSFiddle with my code available here - http://jsfiddle.net/prepin/gzB5k/

Comment: And why can't you use a table?

Comment: @LeviBotelho table does not support variable page width

Comment: It can if you size it using percentage values. If you state exactly what effect you are trying to achieve I'd be happy to try and suggest something.

Comment: your illustration is not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, this cannot be done without JS. The problem lies with the "wrap" element. In order to center it(and it's contents), the width most not be 100%. However, if you set a fixed width, then the element is no longer fluid.

So basically you can only horizontally center `float:left` or `display:inline-block` elements with a "shrink-wrap" effect only if it doesn't reach 100% of it's parent. Once it breaks down to a second line, it's no longer centered.

As you can see from this example in the Fiddle, it cannot be done.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gzB5k/4/

Comment: If he needs a fluid design but the number of element per row is fixed, it can be achieved by wrapping each row in a container.

Comment: @kalema please fiddle. I would like to see this.

Comment: I see what your saying now. That is no different than what I just did in the Fiddle. Like I said, if the number of elements don't reach 100% of it's parent, it can be centered...

Answer (score 2):

It can be done in recent browsers (2013/2014), if you know the maximum number of squares in one row.

Use flex layout and add `max_squares_in_a_row - 1` invisible "squares" that fill the empty positions on last row.

I updated the original snippet:

```css
.square {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.square.empty {
    /* make "placeholders" invisible */
    height: 0;
    /* padding: 0; */
    /* border: 0; */
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.wrap{
    border: 1px solid green;
     
    /* use flex layout here: */
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

.container{
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="square">1</div>
        <div class="square">2</div>
        <div class="square">3</div>
        <div class="square">4</div>
        <div class="square">5</div>
        <div class="square">6</div>
        <div class="square">7</div>
        <!-- add (max squares in row - 1) empty placeholders: -->
        <div class="square empty"></div>
        <div class="square empty"></div>
        <div class="square empty"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check using flex in CSS3, as examples shown [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) it's possible

: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

Would that work: http://jsfiddle.net/gzB5k/3/

You can `margin: 0 auto` the .wrap to center it. But you need to set its width. If you needed the .wrap to be wider, then just use yet another wrapper div. Something like .inner-wrap

On a grid like this, I prefer to use floats rather than inline blocks. It behaves better.

Comment: Does not work for a fluid layout (non-static widths).

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple media queries to set the width of the container. See example below.

You can then center the container with `margin: 0 auto`. Also set a `float:left;` on the .square element instead of `display: inline-block`.

```
@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .wrap {
    width: 500px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 750px) {
  .wrap {
    width: 750px;
  }
}

+ for 1000px, 1250px, 1500px, 1750px
```

In SASS you can use the following snippet.

```
$block-width: 250px;

.wrap {

  width: $block-width;

  @for $i from 1 through 14 {
   @media (min-width : $block-width * $i) {
   width: $block-width * $i;
  }
}
```